# Getting .load Function to work within loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

My page utilises an AJAX .load function to load divs from a separate .html file into a target div on my page.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#about2").click(function() {
 $("#content").load("content.html #about", function() {
 $.getScript("slides.js", function() {
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
 });
});

$("#process2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #process", function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});

$("#materials2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #materials", function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});

$("#pricing2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #pricing", function() {
    $.getScript("tabbedcontent.js", function() {
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
 });
});

$("#radio2").click(function(){
    $("#content2").load("content.html #radiofriendly", function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});
});
```

Basically, within my content.html page (the file where my AJAX grabs the content from) there are .load links WITHIN that content, so basically, my AJAX grabs the content from my content.html, then places it with in the content div in the target page (print.html for example), however i want certain links within the grabbed content, to ALSO activate the load function targeting the div that the content is currently loaded into.

Site is:

http://crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html

And my anchor code WITHIN my content (from my content.html page) that is being loaded into my content div externally that i want to change what is currently in the div is:

```
<a class="content-links" id="materials2" href="#materials">Materials</a>
```

Sorry this is so convoluted, but i can try and explain better if people don't grasp what i'm trying to do.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event binding in jQuery is performed only when the selected element is present in the DOM tree when your relevant JS code is activated. Therefore, you should use `.on()` to allow your script to bind events to newly added elements to the DOM tree.

I assume that, say `#process2` is dynamically loaded into the `#content`. The normal `.click()` binding event will not work. However, you can change it into:

```
$(document).on('click', '#process2', function() {
    $("#content").load("content.html #process", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

This is called event bubbling, where the click event bubbles up to the `document`. Using `.on()`, we tell your script to execute the function when the event originates from `#element2`.

Comment: Thankyou, this has done wonders, another quick one to wrack you're brain, is there a way to use a .load function to load content into a div and also change the html page? i.e Click a link on news.html that will load a div into the #content div in print.html and also change the page to print.html with the targeted content loaded.

Comment: From a different html page, i'd like to funtionalise the above process (loading content from another page into a div) but also change the html page i'm currently on. I think the easiest way is to allow for my AJAX sections to have hyperlink-ability (back, refresh, hotlinking etc functionality) and then just basically use the entire link.